# Personalized Mass Text tool (app)?

Tags: applications, sms, privacy

I want to: Send massive personlized text messages.
Example of what I want to do: Send the same template to George & Juan

- `Hey Juan, how are you doing?`
- `Hey George, how are you doing?`

without having to type the same text twice, if not more.

What I have found so far:

- [Group SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobappli.groupsms): a far from finished and polished App.
- [Mass Text Personalizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.corollarycomputing.mtp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5jb3JvbGxhcnljb21wdXRpbmcubXRwIl0.): a relatively finished but not polished app. It is
  very buggy indeed.

Why I need it: When mass messages are personalized, there is a bigger chance of people replying back.

I need you to: Give me other alternatives to these apps... if there are... better ones.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One nice alternative to the ones you already have is [Group SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobappli.groupsms) by Tur Han available from Google Play Store.

It allows you to compose the message and:

- add first and/or last name to the message text;
- select the recipients individually.

Works pretty good, it's a free app (small publicity banner), with no bugs on my end. Shows the progress of each message being sent.

[image: Group SMS]

If you go to the PRO version, things just keep getting better and better:

> - create groups of contacts for quick sending (friends, family, work...)
> - History keeping & management
> - enhance search bar
> - select/deselect all your contacts with 1 touch
> - template management
> - history track of all messages with statistics
> - add Free